# Cannot understand matplotlib pyplot histogram

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I am just learning some basics of Data Analysis.

I have a simple csv data file like the one below.

```
START,FIRST,SECOND,ITEM
1,100,200,A
2,100,200,B
2,100,300,C
2,200,300,D
3,200,100,E
3,200,100,F
3,200,100,G
3,200,100,H
3,200,100,I
3,200,100,J
```

I wrote this small program to read this csv file and then print a histogram using matplotlib for the three columns START, FIRST, and SECOND. I also print a scatter plot for FIRST vs SECOND columns.

```
#!/exp/anaconda3/bin/python3
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

file_name = 'junk.csv'

data = pd.read_csv(file_name)

print(data.describe())

plt.rcParams['axes.grid'] = True
fix, axs = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(15,10))
axs[0, 0].hist(data['START'], 100, density=True, facecolor='g', alpha=0.8)
axs[1, 0].scatter(data['FIRST'], data['SECOND'], facecolor='violet')
axs[0, 1].hist(data['FIRST'], 100, density=True, facecolor='r', alpha=0.8)
axs[1, 1].hist(data['SECOND'], 100, density=True, facecolor='b', alpha=0.8)
plt.show()
```

[image]

What I do not understand is in the histogram plots, for example, the bottom right hand image with blue bars in the attached picture, why does it not simply plot how many times the number 200 is occurring instead of showing that 200 occurs 0.10 times. How is that possible? Same goes for the 300 as well.

Can someone help me understand what and how matplot is coming up with the Y-axis values? These values do not make sense to me.

Thank you.

Ruby Drew

Answer (score 0):

Try density = False. The density parameter tells matplotlib whether you want it to normalise the heights or not such that it represents a probability density.

Answer (score 0):

First note that a histogram is primarily meant to count continuous samples in small bins.  For discrete data, the bins should be carefully chosen to have boundaries nicely in-between the values. When you add `bins=N`, matplotlib supposes a continuous distribution and subdivides the space from smallest to largest sample into N equally-sized bins. For discrete data this can have unexpected side effects, such as putting samples in either one bin for the values on the bin boundaries.

With `density=True`, the heights of the bars is recalculated such that the total area of all bins sums to 1. For a continuous distribution with many samples, this resembles the [probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) and can be used to draw a [kde plot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html) with the same y-axis.

So, what's happening in the blue histogram:

- 100 bins are created between `100` and `300`. Each bin will be `2` wide.
- 3 bins get values: the bin `100-102` gets count 3, either the bin `198-200` or the bin `200-202` get a count of 1, the bin `298-300` also gets a count of one.
- The total height of the bins is now 5. As their width is 2, the histogram counts need to be divided by `(total_height * bin_width)` to obtain a total area of 1.
- Clearly, the sum of height times width of the bars sums to 1: `0.3*2 + 0.1*2 + 0.1*2 = 1`.

The latest version (`0.11`) of Seaborn's [histplot](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html) has a parameter to indicate that a distribution is discrete. And a parameter `stat=` where you can choose between  `'count'` for bin heights indicating the usual counts and `'probability'` for heights relative to their probability, mimicking a [probability mass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function). The blue histogram could be drawn as:

```py
import seaborn as sns

sns.histplot(data, x='SECOND', discrete=True, stat='probability', facecolor='b', alpha=0.8, ax=axs[1, 1])
```